# Unable to join peers to channel in Hyperledger First Network setup

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following a tutorial on [the Hyperledger fabric site](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) and after installing all the perquisites (latest versions) on a Linux 18.04 installation I run into an error.

I am trying to run the given ./byfn script to "Build Your First Network". After a fresh install I run the commands as follows:

```
./byfn generate
./byfn up
```

At which point everything performs as expected untill the following error occurs 5 times in a row (after which the run exits with an Error):

```
+ peer channel join -b mychannel.block
+ res=1
+ set +x
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
peer0.org1 failed to join the channel, Retry after 3 seconds
```

I have tried various things like:

- Increasing the timeout to allow for longer connection times
- I have down-ed the network and upped it again
- Full re-installations of required packages and the fabric-samples
- Removed all docker volumes/images/containers

I came across some sources mentioning that it might have to do with the peers not being able to connect to each other. Which I tried to fix with a manual docker connect of each peer to the byfn docker network, no success there. I can see the orderer running but the peers that attempted to join the network exited with an error:

```
docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
99570e191542        hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest     "/bin/bash"         24 seconds ago      Up 23 seconds                                        cli
340d1225a913        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   30 seconds ago      Exited (2) 24 seconds ago                            peer0.org1.example.com
fabe017751a0        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   30 seconds ago      Exited (2) 25 seconds ago                            peer1.org2.example.com
f81a639f29f6        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   30 seconds ago      Exited (2) 26 seconds ago                            peer1.org1.example.com
0f91080db681        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   30 seconds ago      Exited (2) 27 seconds ago                            peer0.org2.example.com
c491adc91320        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"           30 seconds ago      Up 28 seconds               0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp   orderer.example.com
```

This shows that the nodes exited with an error code, they all look the same, look below for a docker logs of the peer node.

So my final question is: How do I get the "First Network" Hyperledger sample peers to successfully join the channel?

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1**

I chose a bad code dump! Please use these links for logs/outputs.

- [Full ./byfn up output](http://snippi.com/s/y0xii7p)
- [Docker log output for peer0](http://snippi.com/s/fhmoz5h)

**Update 2**

So I have been trying various things, it seems to not be a go related error but simply a "connection" error where go crashes upon trying to connect a peer to the channel. So the main question at hand is: Why are my docker instances not properly connecting to the channel?

**Update 3**

I have used Amazon Web Services to launch a Linux instance and re-created all my installation steps on this "fresh" instance. Everything worked on the first go (pun intended). Therefore I must conclude that it had to do with either my network settings or personal setup as these are the only parameters that changed.

As this works for me for now I will work with that. I am still open to suggestions and will keep an eye on this post!

**Package versions**

- Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.0
- Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
- docker-compose version 1.13.0, build 1719ceb
- go version go1.11 linux/amd64
- npm: '6.4.1',
- node -v: v8.15.0

Comment: Post the peer logs:
`docker container logs peer0.org1.example.com:7051`

Comment: Can you please check the versions of pr-requisities?

Comment: I have added working links to the logs.

Comment: I have also added specific versions

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to check two things: the memory available and the permissions in the "first-network" directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have made backup of my samples folder and chmoded -R it to 777 for test purposes (horrible security risk, I know!). Nothing changed. As for memory, I have 20 GB free on the Linux partition I am running my dockers on (should be plenty right? I never found any memory requirements for running the Fabric and the total of all docker images amount to about 2.5 GB.)

Comment: So no problem with the memory and the permissions, fine.

Comment: As you pointed out, the go version (go1.10.4) is strange, maybe you have another version installed? If so, perhaps it should be removed and reinstall Fabric again?

Comment: I found out that I had the gopath set improperly. I since removed all other installations of go and reinstalled 1.11. I subsequently set the correct gopath and path variables. When running `go version` in the first-network folder I now get the right version! The problem persists however, I will update the question accordingly.